# Question about Breadboard positioning

Tags: gpio, led, breadboard

That's my current structure:

[image: GPIO]
[image: GPIO 2]

The short metal of the LED (-) is connected to GND, and the longer (+) is in the port 26. This black "thing" (I don't know the name) is connected to my Pi B+ by a gray cable.

My code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time                           

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
delay = 2

def turnon(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, 1)
    return

def turnoff(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, 0)
    return

while(True):      
    turnon(26)
    time.sleep(delay)
    turnoff(26)
    time.sleep(delay)
```

I run this code as root (because it orders me to do that). The problem is that when I execute this code nothing happens. I don't get any errors and the LED doesn't blink.

The Pi I bought was this one: [http://www.amazon.com/CanaKit-Raspberry-Ultimate-Starter-Components/dp/B00G1PNG54](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G1PNG54)

Comment: RESISTOR!!!! You have to connect a resistor serially to your LED or you will fry the pi!

Comment: Thanks. The other guy said about the resistors too. I used some LEDs without the resistor for seconds, I don't know if I ruined a pin, I'll run a test later. The Pi is safe, it's still working and the chip is ok, no visual issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pictures. It appears that you have the cable connected to the board incorrectly. Normally the red stripe on a ribbon cable indicates pin 1. Pin 1 on the Pi is on the SD card end of the board. You can see the pin numbers in this [photo](http://wiki.freepascal.org/File:rpi_gpio_pins.png), and the orientation of the cable in this [picture](http://www.engadget.com/2012/07/02/adafruits-pi-cobbler-breakout-kit-puts-raspberry-pis-pins-to-w/) (this is a board similar to yours produced by Adafuit called the Pi Cobbler).

Comment: Just wondering. The Blue LEDs works normal, bigger in the 3.3 + and smaller in the 3.3 -. But other colors like green didn't work, and the yellow made a little sound and a tiny light in the hole and the Pi reboot =p Maybe those need the resistor?

Comment: The little sound usually means that you have killed it (let out the magic blue smoke). That is what can happen when you don't use a resistor.

Comment: Killed the LED, not the board/role, right? The LED is cheap, I'll buy new ones anyway.

Comment: You probably didn't kill the board but you may have killed a pin.

Comment: pin, you mean, that role? Well, is it cheap to buy a new board like that? Anyway, I'll search about resistors now and try to use that role again to see if it still works

Comment: I mean one of the 26 physical pins on the Pi. Consider a lesson learned to always check your connections twice. Some components have a polarity (they need to be connected a specific way like a battery). A Google search for current limiting resistors LED's should get you started.

Comment: Well, I was afraid I'd kill or at least damage my Pi soon or later. I will buy another one (maybe the new Pi 2) when I learn more about it. Is there a way to check if I really killed one pin in the Pi?

Comment: You could check out this http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/pin-test/. It isn't perfect but it should give you a good idea if something is broken.

Comment: Thanks. And you said something about a blue smoke, but that didn't happen.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke

Comment: Yes, definitely that didn't occur to me. Reading your link I saw "All GPIO peripherals must be removed to perform this test.", does it mean that I need to remove the gray cable from the Pi, or just remove things like button, LED, resistors from the board?

Comment: Better to remove the cable. I would also suggest getting yourself a digital multimeter. Sparkfun.com and adafruit.com have some basic electronics tutorials and adafruit has a whole series of Pi tutorials.

Comment: Just an update: I didn't break any pin in the Pi, I've run a test and everything is fine :)